# Update an object recursively without having to turn it into a map first

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to replace all the Strings nested inside an object via following which kind of works.

But after replacing, the information just seems lost. The original object remains as is without change.

Suspect it's cos I changed the original object which is of type `CustomResponse` to a map.

I had to change it to a map first, else I can't traverse the way I am doing it now.

Is there a way around this to not have to turn it into a map first.

Else I can't traverse the way I am currently doing it.

`CustomResponse` is just an example. There are other objects being passed in like CustomResponse.
Thus I don't want to write logic to specifically cater to CustomResponse but keep it more generic as an object.

Note that I do not want to recreate any new objects, preferably stick to in-place replacement.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

private static ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void parse(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof List) {
        List<Object> arr = (List<Object>) obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            Object o = arr.get(i);
            if (o instanceof String) {
                String str = (String) o;
                arr.set(i, str + " atest");
            } else {
                parse(o);
            }
        }
    } else if (obj instanceof Map) {
        Map<Object, Object> map = (Map<Object, Object>) obj;
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Object o = entry.getValue();
            if (o instanceof String) {
                String str = (String) o;
                entry.setValue(str + " atest");
            } else {
                parse(o);
            }
        }
    } else if (obj instanceof CustomResponse) {
        // likely logic causing issue
        Map<Object, Object> map = MAPPER.convertValue(obj, new TypeReference<Map<Object, Object>>() {});
        parse(map);
    }
}
```

Another consideration was to use reflection like this but feels bit too hacky.

```
else if (obj instanceof CustomResponse) {
    Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object fieldValue = field.get(obj);
        if (fieldValue instanceof String) {
            String str = (String) fieldValue;
            field.set(obj, str + " atest");
        } else {
            parse(fieldValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct.

As String is immutable in `Java` you can't just read the value of the field of the object and then modify that value. Doing so will not affect the field value.

This would work with your `List` and your `Map` code since then you also call the relevant method (`arr.set`, `entry.setValue`) to put this value inside the relevant `list` or `map`.

The respective relevant action to do when modifying a specific object (ex `CustomResponse`) would be to either call the setter with the modified value or to use reflection and modify directly the value of the field.

But what I understand from your code is that you try to add some global configuration for `ObjectMapper` as to how it has to handle an `Object` that has `String` fields so that the produced `JSON` complies with your custom logic. If that is the case then it would be much easier in the following way.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyStringSerializer");
module.addSerializer(String.class, new MyStringSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

while you also need a Serializer Class like the following

```
public class MyStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(
                    String value, 
                    JsonGenerator gen, 
                    SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

        gen.writeString(value + " atest");

    }
}
```

Otherwise if all you want is just to modify the state of an existing object and all it's relative string fields and you thought you could convert it with Jackson to achieve that, I think the part with reflection you just mentioned would be more appropriate. Reflection would also be best to cover your requirement

> Note that I do not want to recreate any new objects, preferably stick
> to in-place replacement.